# Combined sorted-on-the-fly view of two files

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I have two large log files. Both have entries starting with timestamp.

```
 log1.txt:
     2018/03/28-12:00:10 Some text 10
     2018/03/28-12:00:20 Some text 20
     2018/03/28-12:00:30 Some text 30
     ...

 log2.txt:
     2018/03/28-12:00:15 Some text 15
     2018/03/28-12:00:25 Some text 25
     2018/03/28-12:00:35 Some text 35
     ...
```

I want to get a combined view of these two files sorted by timestamp, but without calling expensive *sort* command.

```
 2018/03/28-12:00:10 Some text 10
 2018/03/28-12:00:15 Some text 15
 2018/03/28-12:00:20 Some text 20
 2018/03/28-12:00:25 Some text 25
 2018/03/28-12:00:30 Some text 30
 2018/03/28-12:00:35 Some text 35
```

In other words I want something like this:

```
cat log1.txt log2.txt | sort | less
```

but without sorting the full files, but rather some smart lookahead and sort on the small number of lines.

Anything like this exists?

Answer (score 3):

It looks the both files are already sorted.  Then a merge sort will efficiently 
work.
Try:

```
sort -m log1.txt log2.txt | less
```

The sort command with -m option works just to merge files in order without swapping the lines.